# Manhua where the female lead goes back in time to stop the male lead from killing himself

Tags: story-identification, manga

The story starts out with the female lead watching the original female lead and male lead getting married/engaged. She's very happy for them and down the line she meets the second male lead who I think is banished(?)

He gives her money and food and lets her stay with him, but when she comes back to him with some apples he's killed himself, so she prays at an altar to save him and she wakes up back in time with a bunch of money and buys a title, goes to his house, signs a marriage contract with him and basically claims she's going to take care of him.

She gets his land back from the church (he donated it to the other female lead) and gives it back to him.

Answer (score 4):

This is *[For My Derelict Favorite](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/for-my-derelict-favorite)*. It is available on [Webtoons](https://www.webtoons.com/en/romance/for-my-derelict-favorite/list?title_no=4571&page=1). There are some differences in the specifics of the question, but the major plot points are here.

> What happens after the story ends with a “happily ever after”? When Hestia enters her favorite novel as a side character, she happily fangirls from the sidelines. Thinking she’ll return home when the story reaches its end, Hestia finds that the only thing awaiting her is the tragic death of her favorite character. Now miraculously restored to the day of the ending, Hestia decides that she’ll no longer spectate from the sidelines – instead, she’ll save her derelict favorite!

The protagonist reincarnated in a novel she was a fan of as an inexplicable rich side character. She uses this wealth to purchase a fake title, and uses this to attend balls and other events for nobles that the male lead, female lead, and second male lead of the original story - she's a fan of all of them, but especially the second male lead.

[image: Purchasing a title to attend banquets]

She watches the characters from afar as the events of the novel take place; in particular, the second male lead poisons and kills some people that were threatening the female lead. The female lead is not happy about this, and basically tells him off. This is the banishment - he's not literally banished as far as I can tell, but he's lost the favor of the woman he loves and self-exiles.

After the events of the novel conclude, the main character expects to return to her world but doesn't, and sinks into despair. She eventually meets the second male lead in a forest, running from his servants. They both go to a small cottage. She gets the idea that she's still in this world to take care of him and plans to make some food for him - this is the apples scene. When she returns, he has killed himself.

She eventually prays at an altar and goes back in time to the day of the male lead and female lead's wedding. This is after the poisoning event, so he's in exile. She basically goes to his house, forces her way in, and talks him into a contract marriage, and offers to use her knowledge of the future to help him. This does include a scene where she takes back land donated to the church, since it was basically given for the female lead, not the church in general.