# Isekai manhwa where the white-haired second male lead attempts suicide after the ending

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I'm trying to remember the name of a manhwa I started reading; I think it's fairly new, within the last 3-4 years at least.

I can't remember what the female lead (fl) looks like, but she let the story pass her by, spending her money, and was happy with the ending. She really wanted the second male lead (ml), but he tries to kill himself as he's been abandoned by his friend, the ml, for the fl of the original novel. He succeeds while she's gone (I remember something to do with apples) and she starts to mourn, but time goes back and she starts over. She doesn't squander her money and I believe she even stops an attempt on his life, and the head butler is like "you're so amazing, you must stay here with us" and she's like "oh, I'm a psychic" or something ...

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *[For My Derelict Favorite](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/for-my-derelict-favorite)*, also identified [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/268811). It is available on [Webtoons](https://www.webtoons.com/en/romance/for-my-derelict-favorite/list?title_no=4571&page=1).

> What happens after the story ends with a “happily ever after”? When Hestia enters her favorite novel as a side character, she happily fangirls from the sidelines. Thinking she’ll return home when the story reaches its end, Hestia finds that the only thing awaiting her is the tragic death of her favorite character. Now miraculously restored to the day of the ending, Hestia decides that she’ll no longer spectate from the sidelines – instead, she’ll save her derelict favorite!

The protagonist reincarnated in a novel she was a fan of as an inexplicable rich side character. She uses this wealth to purchase a fake title, and uses this to attend balls and other events for nobles that the male lead, female lead, and second male lead of the original story - she's a fan of all of them, but especially the second male lead.

After the events of the novel conclude, the main character expects to return to her world but doesn't, and sinks into despair. She eventually meets the second male lead in a forest, running from his servants. They both go to a small cottage. She gets the idea that she's still in this world to take care of him and plans to make some food for him - this is the apples scene. When she returns, he has killed himself.

She eventually prays at an altar and goes back in time to the day of the male lead and female lead's wedding. This is after the poisoning event, so he's in exile. She basically goes to his house, forces her way in, and talks him into a contract marriage, and offers to use her knowledge of the future to help him.

Part of her method for forcing her way into his life involves using her knowledge of the world of the book to claim that she's a prophet. She states that she knows the future, and also the existence of a necklace purchased for the original female lead that he was never able to give to her.